# Custom editText clear button

Tags: android, android-edittext, kotlin

I have a custom editText where I want to instanciate a drawable that acts as a clear button, when the user writes on the editText the clear icon appears and if it clicks on it, it clears the text on the editText. But if the user clicks on the editText when the icon is not instanciated it throws a null pointer exception.

Here is the code:

```
class EditTextClearCross : AppCompatEditText, View.OnTouchListener {

    private lateinit var  mClearButtonImage: Drawable

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context){
        setupButton()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context,attrs) {
        setupButton()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context,attrs,defStyle) {
        setupButton()
    }

    private fun setupButton() {
        mClearButtonImage = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_cancel_opaque_14dp, null)!!


        //setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, mClearButtonImage, null)

        addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                if (s?.isEmpty()!!) {
                    setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null)
                } else {
                    mClearButtonImage = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_cancel_black_14dp, null)!!
                    setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, mClearButtonImage, null)
                }
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

            }
        })

        setOnTouchListener(this)
    }

    override fun onTouch(view: View?, motionEvent: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        when (view) {
            this -> {
                Log.d("clear", "yay")
                when (motionEvent?.action!!) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                        if(motionEvent?.rawX!! >= (this.right - this.compoundDrawables[2].bounds.width()!!))
                        setText("")
                    }
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                        view.performClick()

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.compoundDrawables[2]` is going to be null when there is no drawable there.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onTouch` is wrong, as it assumes `this.compoundDrawables[2]` is not null, but `afterTextChanged` actually makes it null in some cases.

Note that `view` and `motionEvent` don't need to be nullable, so your code can be simplified to:

```
override fun onTouch(view: View, motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    Log.d("clear", "yay")
    when (motionEvent.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            this.compoundDrawables[2]?.bounds?.width()?.run {
                // now, `this` refers to the non-null width
                if (motionEvent.rawX >= (this.right - this)) {
                    setText("")
                }
            }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            view.performClick()
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try TextInputLayout's endIconDrawable

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_close"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nav_up"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
    … />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```